# ASUS_T00J zenfone 5 recovery mode shows no command

Tags: recovery-mode, asus-zenfone-5

I have an Asus Zenfone 5 (ASUS_T00J). When I go to recovery mode from droidboot it only shows no command. What might be the problem?

Comment: That isn't a problem. I think another volume button press should help you out (I'm not sure, try pressing or holding all the buttons (singly or in combination) (hold it for less than 2s)).

Answer (score 1):

If this is the same as on Nexus (and I'm not entirely sure that it is but Nexus devices do do this when booting into recovery) then do the following (from the DigitalTrends article [here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/use-recovery-mode-android/)).

"Press and hold the Power key and the Volume up key for around three seconds and then let go of the Volume up key, but keep pressing Power."

After doing this, the recovery options should appear.

Comment: i'll do that but it doesnt work.. i'll press power button + up vol.. it will appear the reboot factory reset i choose all that but my zenfone 5 doesn't fix.

Comment: What are you trying to fix? If the options to Factory Reset, Reboot, etc. appear then recovery is functioning as normal.