# I cant reboot it

Tags: recovery-mode

I keep volume button down and keep power button my htc desire goes to reboot menu but non of selection ( reboot,reset factory.wipe through cache,...) works and it writes NO Command. what should I do?

Comment: Check [related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22no+command%22) maybe? As you neither specified what device nor what Android version you're using, it's hard to give specific advice. [ASUS_T00J zenfone 5 recovery mode shows no command](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133467/16575) looks like a good match, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you root your device ?

With an application by any chance ?

Some applications will root your device, But won't unlock the boot loader !..
This can be a serious problem if you edited your SYSTEM Partition and caused the initial error ...
   - If this happened.
Try going to [HTCDev.com](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader) and sign up for a developer account and start the Unlock process on the site !